# exchanging between tokens on stellar

Tags: exchanges

I am trying to create an app that lets users exchange system-issued (issued by me and delivered to my users) tokens on stellar. the problem is that I can't find anyway of doing so with the included javascript SDK.

how can I do create the exchange operation?

Comment: Is the question about issuing tokens or exchange one token for the other?

Comment: @Francesco exchanging one token for an other

Comment: Can you use the distributed exchange?

Comment: @Francesco I want to know how to do that via the sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to exchange tokens between users is to use the Stellar Distributed Exchange (DEX).

There are two types of operations that let you create offers on the DEX:

- [`Operation.manageBuyOffer`](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Operation.html#.manageBuyOffer): creates an offer, express the amount in units of what you're buying
- [`Operation.manageSellOffer`](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Operation.html#.manageSellOffer): creates an offer, express the amount in units of what you're selling

I included a snippet showing how you can create such transactions and submit them to the network.

```js
    const txA = new Stellar.TransactionBuilder(accountA, { fee })
      .addOperation(Stellar.Operation.manageSellOffer({
          selling: assetX,
          buying: assetY,
          amount: '1000000',
          price: '1',
          offerId: '0',
      }))
      .setTimeout(30)
      .setNetworkPassphrase(Stellar.Networks.TESTNET)
      .build();
    txA.sign(A);
    await server.submitTransaction(txA);

    const txB = new Stellar.TransactionBuilder(accountB, { fee })
      .addOperation(Stellar.Operation.manageBuyOffer({
          buying: assetY,
          selling: assetX,
          buyAmount: '1000',
          price: '1',
          offerId: '0',
      }))
      .setTimeout(30)
       setNetworkPassphrase(Stellar.Networks.TESTNET)
      .build();
    txB.sign(B);
    await server.submitTransaction(txB);
```